# Is there a less expensive method to do the following primary key validation in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I need to make sure the new supplierpart I'm creating doesn't exist. It is currently done like so

```
try {
    entityManager.get(SupplierPartEntity.class,
    new SupplierPartPK(supplierID, partID));

    throw new CreateSupplierPartActionException("Supplier part record exists for " + supplierID
    + " / " + partID + ".");
} catch (final RecordNotFoundException e) {
    /* supplier part not found - do nothing */
}
```

its worth noting entityManager will throw a record not found exception when get() would normally return null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "less expensive" you mean "doesn't hit the database", then no, unless you keep a cache in memory of all existing primary keys. Other than that, the database is the only thing that knows them.

Comment: I know the database hit is required, was trying to avoid an empty catch block, as its the expected path that the logic would follow.

Comment: Is this a question of performance or code style? If performance, don't worry about it unless a profiler is telling you there's a problem. If code style, add a method to your `entityManager` that encapsulates the "does this thing exist" logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'd read that empty catch blocks were a bad practice and was trying to find a more elegant approach. I'll look at encapsulating the "does this exist" It'd still use entiyManager.find(Class.class, PK) and check for null but return a boolean.

Comment: Yes, empty catch blocks are to be scorned, shamed, and ground into non-existence. I didn't quite catch your meaning the first time around. The fact that you have a catch block that seems to not need content suggests an inappropriate abstraction. Pushing the code into an "existence check" method would probably be an appropriate action.

Comment: i think its more a case of an appropriate abstraction (checking for a record and throwing an exception if its not found) being misused as a 'standard' pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the SupplierID and Part ID as a primary key to enforce uniqueness?

Why not go ahead and try to create the new record and catch the uniqueness constraint violation when/if it happens? (Sorry, that item already exists)

Comment: figured (perhaps wrongly) the overhead in handling a not unique constraint would be much more as it would have the SQL Exception thrown at the database, wrapped in the hibernate exception thrown in the ORM (stack trace generated).